# Error in thread ( jdom.jar (Too many open files))

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, struts2

I'm doing a thread to create some inserts in a DB while an Ajax method is sending request to the thread every 0.5s for check the process.
After a while I get the next exception in the catalina output and the thread dies.

Anyone can explain me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using tomcat 7 with struts 2.0.

```java
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:274)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:161)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:115)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:509)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:143)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:115)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:383)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:275)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:161)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:115)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:383)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:275)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:161)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:115)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.map(JSONWriter.java:430)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:140)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:115)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:383)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:275)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:161)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:115)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:82)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:98)
at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at com.humanlike.web.interceptors.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:57)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/tomcat_demo/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/webapps/demo2/WEB-INF/lib/jdom.jar (Too many open files)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:87)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:178)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:705)
at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:1043)
... 92 more
```

Comment: The title seems to suggest you are opening too many files, are you closing files you have finished with?

Comment: What operating system you are using?

Comment: @JonTaylor im not opening any file, this error seems to be from a external library.

Comment: @Sp. im using ubuntu 10.4 but it happens too in a Debian squeeze.

Comment: Try running [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof), which shows all open file descriptors, while it is running.  Look over the list, and see which file or files have a lot open.  Should make it easier to hunt down where they are leaking from.

Comment: Can you explain where/why you are using threads, are you using them in the struts2 action or service layer? I can't think of a reason to create thread in the web tier unless you're working with web sockets as part of your ajax but that is outside of struts2 so shouldn't be part of the stack.

Comment: @Quaternion im using a ajax request to an action who starts a thread for creating some inserts in the DB, this process takes around 40sec-1 min, and I need to show the user the state of the action, that's why I use another ajax requets who  is requesting the thread and showing the user the state of the thread. The weird thing is the deleting action-thread is working ok, and im using the same structure. I reduced the frequency od the ajax request from 0.3 sec to 3 secs and the process works perfect, but with this im hidding the error.

Comment: @Kongol, just to be clear you have some service objects and those objects are working with multiple threads? Your struts2 objects should not be working with multiple threads right? Your making an ajax request to start the process and then make another that simply acquires the single instance of the service object passing in some processing pool id, and that returns something indicating the state of the process which is returned to the user? Just guessing, but jdom should generally be used for outputting xml (view layer) so it should not be bashed by multiple thread access...

Comment: When you make a request on the client, for a particular executableID (checking the status)you are waiting for the result to come back before issuing another right?

Comment: @Quaternion no, it's a setInterval function. Im going to try this and tell you how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Struts 2 and sending request from client through Ajax. Check if you really need to create separate thread for each request.

Struts 2 creates a new Action Object for each new request. So i think you don't need to create threads.

Answer (score 0):

There is limit for how many files can any process open in linux. File in linux is somehow wider than in windows (besides normal files there are also sockets, pipes...). Somewhere in your code you are opening too many files, or probably sockets. So try to figure out where you have resource leaking.

Comment: i know that, but im not working with files, but could it  be a problem with log4j?